# How can i solve "Back-Forward Cache" on Safari Browser without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, safari, event-handling, oracle-apex, browser-cache

I'm using Oracle Apex and currently having problems in only Safari browser on my page that runs different javascript functions for processing. When user uses browser back button, page stuck on the spinner that i put for while waiting process working. When i use other browsers it works as expected and i see the page without processed like before.

I read about back-forward cache issue on Safari causing this, so usual solution was refreshing the page if browser is Safari but i can't do it because refreshing page after process being done broke some other things that i'm currently using. Hiding the spinner also can't be used because i don't want to user change something when page is processed.

So my question is that are there any other solution that i can use to prevent this Safari browser back button issue?